# Can NiFi - SelectHiveQL reads the data from a table on CDH cluster in parquet format?

Tags: apache-nifi, parquet, cloudera-cdh

I have a use case where i have to move data from inhouse CDH cluster to AWS EMR cluster. 
I am thinking to setup NiFi on AWS EC2 instance to moves the data from inhouse cluster to AWS s3 storage.

My all tables on CDH cluster are stored in parquet format.

Question#1: 
Do we have support in NiFi that allows to read tables in parquet format??

OR

The only option that i have is to read data directly from hdfs directory and place it on s3 and then create hive table in EMR?

Question#2: How Nifi determines new data inserted into the table and reads new data. In my case all tables are partitioned by yyyymm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use SelectHiveQL, it can read anything Hive can (including Parquet), all the conversion work is done in Hive and is returned through the JDBC driver as a ResultSet, so you'll get the data out as Avro or CSV depending on what you set as the Output Format property in SelectHiveQL.

Having said that, your CDH would need a Hive version of at least 1.2.1, I've seen quite a few questions about compatibility where CDH has Hive 1.1.x, which NiFi does not support with the Hive processors. For that you'd need something like the Simba JDBC driver (not the Apache Hive JDBC driver, it doesn't implement all the necessary JDBC methods) and you can use ExecuteSQL and other SQL processors with the JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In case if my query is like just "select * from table" Should i assume that everytime NiFi runs it gets the complete snapshot of that table? or does it maintain some kind of checkpointing and only load new data??

Comment: Yep it runs that same query all the time. If you are using a JDBC driver (not the Hive processors), you might be able to use QueryDatabaseTable or GenerateTableFetch to do incremental fetching (i.e. loading only new data).